# Controlling DDL generation in Toplink Essentials

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, constraints, cascade, toplink

I am having some trouble with the DDL generation of Toplink Essentials. I am developing a Glassfish 2.1 based application and use JPA for persistence.

I have an object graph where a parent entity of class A owns a set of entities of class B. Entites B come in several flavors which is modelled using inheritance. One such flavor is a composite entity class BC that bundles a set several other B entites. All entites B in a BC must also be owned by the same entity A as B. Note that not all entites B of an entity A have to be part of a composite BC, they can also be standalone.

So basically that maps to the following classes:

```
@Entity
class A {
  @ManyToOne(mappedBy="owner", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE })
  Set<B> bs;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance
abstract class B {
  @Id
  long id;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE })
  A owner;

  @ManyToOne(optional = true)
  BC composite;
}

@Entity
class BC extends B {
  @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE }, mappedBy = "composite")
  Set<B> parts;
}
```

When toplink generates the DDL for this object hierarchy it creates all foreign key constraints as expected. However it does not set cascading rules for the constraints.

When I now try to delete an entire object graph via a reference to the A instance there can be situations where toplink fails to correctly remove the graph from the database. When toplink deletes a BC entity before deleting the contained B entities the foreign key constraint for the "composite" relationship is violated.

This situation can be corrected by manually adjusting the generated DDL to CASCADE (or SET NULL) on the relevant foreign key constraint which is fine for a production environment. This however fails in a test environment with in-memory (Derby) databases where DDL generation is managed entirely by toplink essentials and thus leads to the constraint violation described above.

Is there any way to influence the DDL generation process such that the required cascading rules are correctly set by toplink essentials?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an issue with DDL generation, but with deletion.

TopLink Essentials had some issues with resolving deletes from complex object graphs, or cyclic relationships.  The are a few workarounds, such as deleting the dependent objects first and calling flush, then deleting the other objects, or setting the foreign key to null so they get updated.  Using a customizer to mark the mapping privateOwned, or play with the constraint dependency may also work.  You can also drop or defer the constraints.

All of the deletion issues have been fixed in EclipseLink, so upgrading the to latest EclipseLink release should resolve the issue.

EclipseLink also supports an @CascadeOnDelete annotation to add the cascade to the constraint in DDL generation.